# How do i remove the spining issue, semi transparent clone image when my cricket ball is in motion

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, motion-blur

I'm experiencing an issue in my 2D cricket game where the ball appears with three semi-transparent ball images when it's thrown and in motion in 2D space. It seems like the ball texture creates three different texture image during motion in 2D space : one on the left side of the main ball texture, one in the middle with high contrast, and another  ball texture on the right side and left-right ball texure are semi-transparent. Are there any solutions to resolve this problem?Here is the video Link where ball is creating illusion like it spining  :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZ0czmkXOEs&ab_channel=ShakilHassan

I have tried all the way like using motion blur from post processing, reducing fixed time step, tried with different texure of the ball. But still not finding the right solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Im not quite sure if I'm understanding your problem, but in the video you linked, the ball looks completely fine. Pausing it shows that it isn't actually rendering anything you wouldn't want so I believe there isn't really a way to get rid of this "effect" as It is purely a visual thing that's unrelated to Unity.